# Windows Phone Launch App with Voice Commands in Cortana

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, cortana

I'm trying to figure out how to launch an app (WP 8.1 RT) in the foreground using Cortana. I found this link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn630430.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I can create the VCD file fine, the problem is the below namespace doesn't exist, so I can't install the VCD xml commands.

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands;
```

Am I missing a DLL? I can't seem to find it. Also, I'm using VS2013 and Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow [this documentation for 8.x](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206959(v=vs.105).aspx). The namespace you want is [`Windows.Phone.Speech.VoiceCommands`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.speech.voicecommands.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Peter. So the documentation you provided is for Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight apps right? I'm just building a quick prototype, so I'm fine with using a Silverlight app. I noticed that Windows.Phone.Speeh.VoiceCommands namespace isn't recognized in Windows 8.1 RT apps. So is it not supported for Universal Apps yet?

Comment: Windows 8.1 doesn't support Voice Commands at all. Windows 10 (all devices) supports Voice Commands via the namespace in your original question.