# Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App: How to listen to user's voice commands in background?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, voice-recognition, cortana

I'm developing on Windows Runtime and Universal App (8.1) but I don't have any experience about this topic.

Is it possible to make a vocal command to perform the same action that now I do with a button?
For example the user could click the button "start" or say the voice command "start". How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.  [This Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185608.aspx) is on a similar note. Most of the windows 10 API for speech are similar to those for the windows 8.1 Universal.

Answer (score 0):

Starting an app this way isn't possible with Windows Phone 8.1 Run Time. It is with Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight, and Windows Phone 10 universal apps. Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526955/windows-phone-launch-app-with-voice-commands-in-cortana)

Comment: I don't want to start an app, but start a command inside the app